# TreeView: Place selection indicator along the item at the left edge of the control

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, controltemplate

So the requirement is simple, but the solution doesn't seem to be (or at least I haven't succeeded yet). I need to display a vertical bar at the left side of the currently selected item of the `TreeView` control. Something like this:

[image]

Problem I'm facing is that with child items, this indicator also moves towards right, as it is part of the `ItemTemplate`, like this:

[image]

This is undesirable. I need the red indicator to stick to the left edge of the control, like this:

[image]

I can see why this happens. The `ItemsPresenter` in `TreeViewItem` template introduces a left margin of 16 units, which causes the all child items to move right-wards as well. I can't figure out how to avoid it.

Note: The red bar is a `Border` with `StrokeThickness` set to `4,0,0,0`. It encompasses the `Image` and `TextBlock` elements inside it, though this doesn't directly have anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware, since the left vacant space is outside of `ItemsPresenter` which hosts the content of `TreeViewItem`, you cannot accomplish it by ordinary Style.

Instead, a workaround would be to change the bar to an element such as `Rentangle` and move it to the edge of `TreeView`. For example, it can be done by an attached property which is to be attached to the element and move it to the edge of TreeView with a specified left margin.

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

public static class TreeViewHelper
{
    public static double? GetLeftMargin(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double?)obj.GetValue(LeftMarginProperty);
    }
    public static void SetLeftMargin(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(LeftMarginProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftMarginProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LeftMargin", typeof(double?), typeof(TreeViewHelper), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnValueChanged));

    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((d is FrameworkElement element) && (e.NewValue is double leftMargin))
        {
            element.Loaded += (_, _) =>
            {
                TreeView? tv = GetTreeView(element);
                if (tv is null)
                    return;

                Point relativePosition = element.TransformToAncestor(tv).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
                element.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(leftMargin - relativePosition.X, 0);
            };
        }
    }

    private static TreeView? GetTreeView(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        DependencyObject test = element;
        while (test is not null)
        {
            test = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(test);
            if (test is TreeView tv)
                return tv;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

This workaround does not depend on how to show/hide the bar upon selection of the `ListViewItem`. Although the question does not provide the actual code for this, if you implement a mechanism to change `BorderBrush` upon selelection, you can modify it to change `Fill` of the bar (in the case of `Rectangle`).

Comment: Thanks. How am I supposed to update it upon selection?

Comment: We don't know your intention upon selection because you don't provide any code. But anyways, as you can see, the movement will be done when that element is loaded. In othwe words, when a ListViewItem which includes that element is first shown.

Comment: Thanks again. Perhaps you missed it (or I didn't explain it well enough in the OP), the red bar to the left shows the currently selected `TreeViewItem` and should be moved when user clicks a different item.

Comment: Well, how to show/hide the bar itself is not included in your question.

Comment: *I need to display a vertical bar at the left side of the **currently selected item***... doesn't that say something? The red bar is simply a selection indicator and obviously needs to move with selection, just like shown in the 3 screenshots.

Comment: Well, I am talking about how you implement to show/hide the bar. There will be a number of ways for this.